# Pidgin will not receive files

Tags: linux, file-transfer, chat, pidgin

Anytime someone tries to send me files over YIM or AIM when I am using Pidgin 2.7.5 on Arch Linux, it fails mid-transfer, telling me that they cancelled, and telling them that I cancelled.

The same computer using Pidgin on Windows manages to transfer these files successfully.

Is there some sort of checklist for these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently a known and still open bug in Pidgin : [Ticket #12472](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/12472).

The only hint for a solution comes from [Ticket #2973](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/2973) (closed), which seems to imply that ports 5190-5290 must be open in the firewall.

However, if this isn't a firewall problem, then the only solution is to wait for the resolution of the bug.

Answer (score 1):

The port Pidgin is using to transfer files may be blocked. From [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=583435):

> Turn Firestarter on and let it block you from sending the file. Then look in Firestarters log and see what port your file transfer was using, then allow that port in "outgoing connections" and update your policy list

Comment: I haven't a clue what Firestarter is, and it isn't on my system, while it was causing the listed problem.

Comment: Just checked. it is not being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Wireshark to look at the network traffic when sending/receiving fails.

(FYI, Firestarter is a front end for iptables, which is the typical firewall in Linux.)

Answer (score 0):

Pidgin uses TRAC as issue managment tool. If the bug is known, you should be able to find it on http://developer.pidgin.im/query. Are you using the latest version? Have you tried installing it from source to maybe get a newer version?

Comment: Read my answer.